# application close without error messages

Tags: android

I am trying to send my object Product from Activity B to Activity A, when the app close without any error message:

Activity A:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent addManualProduct;
TextView name;
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_product);

    addManualProduct = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    setTitle("ACTIVITY A");

    Button openB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_OpenActB);
    openB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(addManualProduct, 2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Product p = data.getParcelableExtra("product_new");
        name.setText(p.getName());
        img.setImageBitmap(p.getImg());
    }
}
```

}

Activity B:

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    setTitle("ACTIVITY B");
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);

    Product product = new Product("arroz", img);
    Intent toA = new Intent();
    toA.putExtra("product_new", product);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, toA);
    finish();
}
```

}

Product object:

```
    public class Product implements Parcelable{
String name;
Bitmap img;

public Product() {}

public Product(String name, Bitmap img){
    this.name = name;
    this.img = img;
}

protected Product(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    img = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeParcelable(img, flags);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Product> CREATOR = new Creator<Product>() {
    @Override
    public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Product(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Product[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Product[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Bitmap getImg() {
    return img;
}
```

}

If I only make parcelable the String name its works ok but when I try to put the Bitmap it close all application.
I can say the error its because the Bitmap, but I don't know why.

Comment: I think your issue may be the `ClassLoader` you are using to read in the `Bitmap`. Try passing in `null` so that it will use the default `ClassLoader`. If that doesn't work, it is possible that the bitmap is too large and can't be parcelled.

Answer (score 0):

Parcelling large data can cause issues in your application. Instead of parcelling the `Bitmap`, I suggest parcelling the resource instead.

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
    String name;
    int bitmapResource;

    public Product(String name, int resource){
        this.name = name;
        this.bitmapResource = resource;
    }
}
```

Then you can use your `Product` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    setTitle("ACTIVITY B");

    Product product = new Product("arroz", R.drawable.no_image);
    Intent toA = new Intent();
    toA.putExtra("product_new", product);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, toA);
    finish();
}
```

If you need to load `Bitmap`s in a more dynamic fashion, you can store the `Uri` to your `Bitmap` so that it can be loaded from raw resources, assets, or from a service.

Comment: I am gonna use URI as you recommend. Anyway the bitmap I am actually using is a PNG and it got 11,39K size, it can be considered as large data?

Comment: Yes, I would consider that large data. My recommendation is to only parcel small items like strings, numbers, enums, other Parcelable model classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap which you are passing might too big.
So try to compress bitmap.
Try below example :-

http://www.android-examples.com/compress-bitmap-image-in-android-and-reduce-image-size/